# Trying to test an angular controller with jasmine - errors

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am very new to angular/jasmine/karma and I'm having trouble getting a test written for my controller.  The test itself is running successfully, but in the test running I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: userFactory() method does not exist
```

userFactory() is a method call made in my controller to a service that returns a promise.  I'm not sure how to make sure this is correctly defined in the test.

Here is my code:

*app.js*

```
    (function () {
    angular.module('mdotTamcCouncil', ['mdotTamcCouncil.core', 'blurb']);

    angular.module('mdotTamcCouncil.core', []);
})();
```

*blurb-service.js*

```
(function () {
    angular.module('mdotTamcCouncil.core').factory('blurbsFactory', function ($http) {
        var promise = null;

        return function () {
            if (promise) {
                // If we've already asked for this data once,
                // return the promise that already exists.
                return promise;
            } else {
                promise = $http.get(jsGlobals.blurbsDataURL);
                return promise;
            }
        };
    });
})();
```

*user-service.js*

```
(function () {
    angular.module('mdotTamcCouncil.core').factory('userFactory', function ($http) {
        var promise = null;

        return function () {
            if (promise) {
                // If we've already asked for this data once,
                // return the promise that already exists.
                return promise;
            } else {
                promise = $http.get(jsGlobals.userDataURL);
                return promise;
            }
        };
    });
})();
```

*blurb-controller.js*

```
(function () {
    angular.module('blurb')
            .controller('BlurbController', ['$scope', 'blurbsFactory', 'userFactory', function ($scope, blurbsFactory, userFactory) {
                $scope.content = "";
                $scope.blurbs = {};
                $scope.currentUser = {};
                this.editMode = false;


                userFactory().success(function (data) {
                    $scope.currentUser = data;
                });

                blurbsFactory().success(function (data) {
                    $scope.blurbs = data;
                    $scope.content = $scope.blurbs[$scope.textKey];
                });

                this.enterEditMode = function () {
                    this.editMode = true;
                };

                this.saveEdits = function () {
                    this.editMode = false;
                    $scope.blurbs[$scope.textKey] = $scope.content;
                };
            }]);

})();
```

*blurb-module.js*

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('blurb', ['ngSanitize', 'mdotTamcCouncil.core']);

})();
```

and my test spec:

```
describe('BlurbController', function () {
    var scope, controllerService;

    beforeEach(module('mdotTamcCouncil'));
    beforeEach(module('mdotTamcCouncil.core'));
    beforeEach(module('blurb'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controllerService = $controller;
    }));

    it("should get 'user' from 'data/user.json'", inject(function ($httpBackend) {
        $httpBackend.expectGET("data/user.json").respond({"userName": "myera","email": "something@something.com","isAdmin": true});
        $httpBackend.expectGET("data/blurbs.json").respond('{"mainPageIntro": "<h2>Welcome</h2>"}');
        ctrl = controllerService('BlurbController', { $scope: scope });
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(scope.currentUser).toEqual({"userName": "myera","email": "something@something.com","isAdmin": true});
        expect(scope.blurbs).toEqual({ "mainPageIntro": "<h2>Welcome</h2>" });
    }));
});
```

I've pieced this together from reading blogs and stackoverflow answers.  I'm not sure that I'm even doing it correctly.

The tests themselves actually pass, but I am getting the error in the console about the missing "userFactory()" method.  I assume I would also get the message for the "blurbFactory()" method if it was getting that far.  I don't believe I can test the actual functionality of the controller without first resolving these errors.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks so much for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue you are seeing is because you didn't include the 'mdotTamcCouncil.core' module as a dependency in the blurb module.  When defining it, you should be able to pass in a list of dependencies using

```
angular.module('blurb', ['mdotTamcCouncil.core']);
```

You are only getting the one console error because the execution stops when the userFactory() fails.  I'm not sure why the tests are showing as passing, it should pick up the exceptions and fail - could be an oddity with your chosen test runner.

Comment: Thanks so much for your feedback, @Travis.  Unfortunately, I do have "mdotTamcCouncil.core" defined in my blurb module.  I have updated my question to show the contents of blurb-module.js.  Thanks again!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure I'm going to be much more help.  I plugged your samples into a quick test project and the only issues I ran into were the blurb module not loading properly. I resolved this by changing the way the modules are created.  Essentially I removed the blurb-module file and updated blurb-controller to instantiate the module there.  Once that was fixed the tests ran and passed with no console errors.

Comment: thank you tons! I played around with where the module declaration was being made, and eventually got it working.  I am wondering if my karma test runner wasn't properly loading blurb-module.js.  I restarted it after modifying the karma config and then it worked.  You got me on the right track though.  Thank you. =)